# jquery javascript override / extend event

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I have an element with event set, e.g.

```
<input type="text" id="txt" onkeyup="javascript: alert('keyup');" />
```

Now, I want to intercept this event and run some other script in addition to default one.
I wrote following code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

var old = $("#txt").keyup;

$("#txt") 
     .unbind('keyup')
     .attr('onkeyup', '')
     .each(function() { this.onkeyup = null; });

$("#txt").keyup(function(event){

    alert("before old call");
    //old.call($(this));
    alert("after old call");
});

});
```

But it is not working as I expected. Anybody knows how to make this working?

Link to fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/p5JeA/

What if the keyup event for the input is not inlined, but set using jQuery bind?
I want to override/extend the default behaviour, I do not want to change the base code.

Comment: It works fine for me, you forgot to include the jQuery in the jsFiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/RikudoSennin/p5JeA/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mrchief/p5JeA/2/

```
var old = $("#txt")[0].onkeyup;

$("#txt")[0].onkeyup = null; // or function () {};
// or $("#txt").removeAttr('onkeyup');
```

jQuery was not included in the resources. Also, I commented out some parts as you don't need them.

Comment: Will that call `removeEventListener`?

Comment: Thanks so much! @CodeReaper's answer below is also helpful. Looks like I tend to forget about jQuery returning a collection of matched elements.

Comment: Why do you query the `DOM` **twice**? You do nothing with `old`.

Comment: @gdoron: `old` preserves the oldehandler, in case you want to restore it later. You don't need to query DOM twice, of course. This is meant to be a quick example, not production ready code.

Answer (score 1):

I have forked your fiddle to here : http://jsfiddle.net/xdaTH/

I have turned on jQuery instead of MooTools, but also using .get(0) to get the actual dom element which has a onkeyup function defined.

script:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  var old = $("#txt").get(0).onkeyup;

  $("#txt").unbind('keyup').attr('onkeyup', '').each(function() {
      this.onkeyup = null;
  });

  $("#txt").keyup(function(event) {
    alert("before old call");
    old.call(this);
    alert("after old call");
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Create your own custom event and then trigger it:

```
$('#txt').bind('custom', function(event) {
   alert("before old call");
    //old.call($(this));
    alert("after old call");
});

$('#txt').trigger('custom', ['Custom', 'Event']);
```

You can find out info on it here: [jquery trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)